# Indentation error: expected an indented block ,in python

Tags: python, indentation, function-definition

recently started learning to use python and I'm trying to make a basic text-based game, and I have run into a slight issue with a function definition where it says there is an indentation error with an elif statement (elif hit_c == 1),(also note I have imported all the needed libraries and defined all variables in the function)

```
def damage(x):
    """ This function will determine the amount of damage you will take """
    """ hit_c is the chance the enemy has to hit you """
    global User_HP
    global Enemy_HP

    hit_c = randint(1,5)
    User_damage = randint(1,4)

    if hit_c >= 2:
        Enemy_HP -= User_damage
        print(f"You dealt {User_damage} damage!")
        print(Enemy_HP)
        if Enemy_HP < 0:

    elif hit_c == 1:
        print("You missed!")

    hit_c = randint(1,5)
    Enemy_damage = randint(1,3)

    if hit_c >= 2:
        User_HP -= Enemy_damage
        print(f"You took {Enemy_damage} damage!")
        print(User_HP)
```

I don't see any problem with my indentations in my function and not sure why this statement, in particular, is having an error. Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Missing result in your `if Enemy_HP < 0:` logic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
    if Enemy_HP < 0:

elif hit_c == 1:
```

You forgot to finish the `if` statement on the first line.